# Erase Canvas SandLab.java

Tags: java, arrays, eraser

I am creating a game on java, and I would like to reset the whole canvas after painting on the screen. I would like to do this by adding a button on the side of the game, but I am not sure where to add this in my code. The general format of the code is SandLab.java. Would anyone know what area to implement this in?

Comment: Please provide more specific details about the `SandLab.java`